# Protecting fine pitch components from debris

Tags: pcb

I am making a Battery Management System. However the chips I am using are the LTC-6803-4 chips, and they have a pitch of just 0.5mm. The boards will be placed in a battery box with good ventilation, however I am worried that a stray metal shaving might come across the chip and short out multiple pins.

I am looking for a way to protect the chips in case metal shavings do find a way to enter the box. My first thought was hot glue, but I still need adiquite ventilation of the chips, and I am not sure about the conductive properties of hot glue.

I am sure this problem has come up in industry many times, but I just cant seem to find a simple solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: "Conformal coating" may be what you're looking for.

Comment: We use conformal coating P/N 422B-340G (http://www.alliedelec.com/search/productdetail.aspx?SKU=70125743). We have had excellent results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cheesecloth, stockings or any other fine thin material over the vents.

And I have yet to find a conductive hotglue. Don't cover the entire chip, just the leads.

Answer (score 2):

Mount the PCB upside down, on the "roof" of the enclosure.  That way, any debris that gets inside will fall to the bottom and not settle on your PCB.

Of course, doing the other things helps too:  air filters, conformal coatings, air baffles, etc.